# An exercise Using Setters- Getters + a simple GUI with a button ( JAVA ) *Stuck*

Tags: java, arrays, constructor, jbutton, getter-setter

I am a student.So you might face a couple of errors or amateur mistakes.. I have the following exercise given to me by a teacher so I can practice Java (since its been almost a year since i've first programmed in java)

Description :Class -> Make a sandwitch (defined by Weight (int) , the amount of incredients in it (int) and its price (int).

- Make a class for it . Set a constructor for it ( +   setters + getters) .
- Create a button that whenever gets pressed it creates a couple of sandwitches and puts them inside a 50 block  array.
- Put inside your code any logical Exceptions (for the price not <=0 i assume :) )
- Make a button that outputs a message about the lowest price of a 5 incredient sandwitch in a window dialog.

I believe that the following code is enough for the first step ..
But i am stuck on the 2nd- 3rd step.. I am using Netbeans IDE 8.2
And its been a year since I first touched java so i m pretty rusty but eager to learn and get back to coding .. If anyone could help me out with this problem i 'd be gratefull .

```
public class Sandwitches {

    public static int price;
    public static int incredients;
    public static int weight;

    Sandwitches(int price, int incredients, int weight) {
        this.price = price;
        this.incredients = incredients;
        this.weight = weight;
    }

    public void setPrice(int price) {
        this.price = price;
    }

    public void setInc(int incredients) {
        this.incredients = incredients;
    }

    public void setWeight(int weight) {
        this.weight = weight;
    }

    public int getPrice() {
        return this.price;
    }

    public int getInc() {
        return this.incredients;
    }

    public int getWeight() {
        return this.weight;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)

    { 

        Sandwitches me = new Sandwitches(2, 3, 20);
        if (price >=0){
        System.out.println("I cost:" + me.getPrice());

        System.out.println("My weight is:" + me.getWeight());

        System.out.println("I currently have:" +me.getInc()+ "incredients");

    }
        else 
        {
            System.out.println("The price has to be a positive number ");
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: You can create a GUI with JavaFX. For a starter on JavaFX read Oracle's tutorial: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/get-started-tutorial/javafx_get_started.htm

Comment: Thank you for your quick response ! I ll check it out!